# Exact String match using oracle CONTAINS for multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, contains

I need to get exact name string match from multiple values using **Contains** function.

I used below query to get data which matches exactly JOHN SMITH OR MIKE DAVID but query is fetching all data which has JOHN SMITH, JOHN, SMITH, MIKE, DAVID, MIKE DAVID, JOHN..SMITH, JOHN/SMITH,....

```
where contains(names,'{JOHN SMITH} OR {MIKE DAVID}')>0
```

**Note** - I don't want to use multiple like in OR conditions.We need to pass around 200 to 300 values (names) to do match pattern.

Can anyone let me know how to get exact match from multiple values using CONTAINS?

Thanks
Anand

Comment: Put the 200 to 300 values in a separate table. JOIN.

Comment: just for example i mentioned column name as names but actually it is comments column which is CLOB

Comment: Please share sample input and output datasets , mentioning their datatypes. Otherwise it's very challenging to solve for.

Comment: Case_id, Case_type,Case_comments
100 xx     Fraudlent activity on John.Smith account
200 yy     John Smith account is blocked 
300 zz     David account with co-applicant as John
400 xx     transaction exceed for David Mike
500  aa     Frequently accessed by John Smith and DAVID MIKE

Comment: Case_comments is CLOB datatype. We need to get list of case id's with exact name match from comments . Names to check (Input) JOHN SMITH and DAVID MIKE                                        output - 200, 400, 500

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `Oracle` but i liked this question and i will try to answer it based on what i read on `Oracle's` documentation, regarding `CONTAINS`.

so i am currently reading about [`Stored Query Expression (SQE)`](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/text.102/b14218/cqoper.htm),

**Stored Query Expression (SQE)**

> Use the SQE operator to call a stored query expression created with
> the `CTX_QUERY.STORE_SQE` procedure.
>
> Stored query expressions can be used for creating predefined bins for
> organizing and categorizing documents or to perform iterative queries,
> in which an initial query is refined using one or more additional
> queries.

So perhaps you could pass all the names you want to query in such a way. For example:

```
begin
ctx_query.store_sqe('mynames', 'JOHN SMITH OR MIKE DAVID OR GEORGE HARRIS OR JOHN DOE');
end;
```

And then call it:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), nameid FROM mytable
WHERE CONTAINS(names, 'sqe(mynames)', 1)> 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1);
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi Peter, Appreciate your response. This is a requirement for Reporting application wherein users will create Adhoc reports. I guess this solution cannot be implemented For Adhoc requirement.

Comment: @Anand It seems kind of too much to use a stored expression for this, but then again it depends on what you are letting the user store on his/her account in the application you are creating. I think it is a cool feature for every user that uses a reporting interface to be able to store some custom reports. All that comes down to how an application is built, but as said it seems a bit too much. I think if the stored expression could be re-useable for more than one query then there is a lot of logic on using it. Does this answer solve the exact match problem?

Comment: this will work for predefined/ standard reporting requirements. We can create SQE and call with in predefined query.But not sure about Adhoc requirements.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have tried SQE method but still results are same as CONTAINS. JOHN.SMITH is also returned in the output.